# XeLaTeX, fontspec and printing the name of the current font

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Is it possible, using XeLaTeX and `fontspec.sty`, to write a macro, say, `\printcurrentfont`, such that it would print the name of the font currently in use? I have looked through the `fontspec` documentation, but so far have not found an answer.

Comment: What is the name you want to see? file name? internal font name? family name used by fontspec?

Comment: Any and all of those, depending on the information that I need to output. I am putting together a number of samples of  typefaces and I would like to label them with the name of the current font being sampled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the internal and the external names of the current font respectively with `\the\font` and `\fontname\font`. The former must be stringified in order to print it.

Further massaging of the external font name can be added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily{\junicode}{Junicode}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textttup}{\normalfont\ttfamily}

\newcommand{\printinternalcurrentfont}{%
  \expandafter\textttup\expandafter{\expandafter\string\the\font}%
}
\newcommand{\printexternalcurrentfont}{%
  \expandafter\textttup\expandafter{\fontname\font}%
}

\begin{document}

\printinternalcurrentfont

\printexternalcurrentfont

\bigskip

{\itshape\printinternalcurrentfont\par\printexternalcurrentfont}

\bigskip

\sffamily

\printinternalcurrentfont

\printexternalcurrentfont

\bigskip

\junicode

\printinternalcurrentfont

\printexternalcurrentfont

\end{document}
```

### Output with XeLaTeX

[image]

### Output with LuaLaTeX

[image]

If you're not interested in the finer details, but just in the main font name part, change the definition of `\printexternalcurrentfont` into

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printexternalcurrentfont}{%
  \expandafter\format@externalcurrentfont\fontname\font:\@nil
}
\def\format@externalcurrentfont#1:#2\@nil{%
  \textttup{\@ifnextchar"{\@gobble}{}#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

The output would become

[image]

Comment: `\fontname\font` reveals the main font name, how does one reveal the mono or sans font name?

Comment: @MatteoS `{\sffamily\printinternalcurrentfont\par\printexternalcurrentfont}` for the sans font, use `\ttfamily` instead for the mono font.

Comment: I don't get that. The format I'm getting for \printexternalcurrentfont is the TTF font file name in square brackets before the /OT. How would I go about getting just the font name without the square brackets or the .ttf or the /OT or anything else?

Comment: @PeterFlynn It depends on how you load the font. In the example I loaded fonts installed system-wide.

Comment: Same, but it was my fault: I was reading the wrong command (int not ext).

Comment: Note that in the external font, with XeLaTeX the "/OT" is included, while with LuaLaTeX it is not. For consistency, one must strip the "/OT" part in the XeLaTeX case as well.

Comment: Actually not just the "/OT" mentioned in the previous comment, but there are other inconsistencies between xelatex and lualatex: with the former there are spaces and (for only some fonts) a "Regular" suffix that is not present with lualatex. Oh well… giving up on consistency.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR For instance, italic might be denoted by appending `/I` with XeLaTeX and with `Italic` with LuaLaTeX. Different approach by the engine (actually by `luaotfload` in case of LuaLaTeX).

Comment: @egreg Ah I see, thanks for explaining! The situation is not ideal, but makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the usable answer is much simpler:

```
\newcommand{\printexternalcurrentfont}{%
  \expandafter\getfontname\fontname\font:\@nil}
\def\getfontname"[#1.#2\@nil{#1}
```

You just need to parse out all the stuff except the actual font name. Unfortunately it does not give you the user-friendly name (eg Raleway Regular) but retains the hyphens. But it's close.