# How to use \addCJKfontfeatures?

Tags: fonts, xecjk, ctex

The `ctex` bundle provides `Mapping = fullwidth-stop` to convert ordinary Chinese periods (。) to fullwidth periods (．). (Not to be confused with halfwidth periods (.).)

However, this only works for one font.

```
\documentclass[UTF8, fontset = fandol]{ctexart}

\setCJKmainfont{FandolSong}[%
  Mapping = fullwidth-stop
]

\begin{document}

天地玄黄，宇宙洪荒。盖此身发，四大五常。

\kaishu
天地玄黄，宇宙洪荒。盖此身发，四大五常。

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `kaishu` font is not altered. Of course I can do it separately for `kaishu`, but then I also have to do for `fangsong`, `heiti`, etc. I would like to do it for all fonts in one place.

The documentation mentions `\addCJKfontfeatures`. I tried to use it:

```
\documentclass[UTF8, fontset = fandol]{ctexart}

\addCJKfontfeatures{Mapping = fullwidth-stop}

\begin{document}

天地玄黄，宇宙洪荒。盖此身发，四大五常。

\kaishu
天地玄黄，宇宙洪荒。盖此身发，四大五常。

\end{document}
```

However, this didn't function:

[image]

`\addCJKfontfeatures*` didn't help either. What is the correct way to use `\addCJKfontfeatures`? How to set the mapping for all fonts in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
% cancel CJK font declarations at class loading
\documentclass[fontset=none]{ctexart}

% change default CJK font features
\defaultCJKfontfeatures{Script=CJK, Mapping=fullwidth-stop}
% declare CJK fonts, with new default features applied
\ctexset{fontset=fandol}

\begin{document}
天地玄黄，宇宙洪荒。盖此身发，四大五常。

\kaishu
天地玄黄，宇宙洪荒。盖此身发，四大五常。
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the documentation of package [`xeCJK`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf),

- `\addCJKfontfeatures` only affects *the* currently used font, so after you change to a new font by `\kaishu`, new font feature disappears.
- `\defaultCJKfontfeatures` affects *every* following font declarations, hence is what you need.

By the way, option `Mapping` is defined in `fontspec` package, then package `xeCJK` inherits it and provides four mapping files (including the one OP used), finally `ctex` bundle loads `xeCJK` to declare CJK fonts.

Comment: Excellent!  This seems like the canonical solution.  Just to make sure I understood correctly: I think `\addCJKfontfeatures`, which does "临时增加当前使用的CJK字体的选项" per doc, doesn't work because there is no "当前使用的CJK字体" in the preamble.  Moving it inside the `document` makes it work, but the changes cease to apply when the font is changed.  Am I right?  If that is right, then everything makes sense to me now :)

Comment: @L.F. Yes, you are right.

Comment: Just curious: is there a way to retroactively add features to the fonts already loaded, thereby avoiding the need for `fontset`ing separately?

Comment: It is possible but currently not implemented. 1. Font features are stored in (internal) font changing commands only. So, to add feature is to redefine commands. 2. `xeCJK` does not keep a defined-font-changing list, hence it did not know the name list of declared font changing commands. 3. Both restrictions are inherited from `fontspec`.

Comment: The command name and font features of current font can be retrieved by `\expandafter\string\the\font` and `\fontname\font`, respectively (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303536)). This is how `\addCJKfontfeatures` works.

Comment: When using this solution, it gives many "Undefined control sequence." errors for math, even I remove the `defaultCJKfontfeatures` command. Any idea why this happens? I'm using `ctexbook` documentclass.

Comment: @YijunYuan My answer need xetex engine. Which engine do you use? Perhaps you can post a new question with more info.