How to display playing card symbols ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣ of all fonts
I would like to compare the playing card symbols ♠ ♥   ♦   ♣ of different fonts.
In the following MWE I display the 4 symbols for an example font.
How could I display this (if available)
in a loop for all installed system fonts (or LaTeX fonts)?

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\T[]{Arial.ttf}

% Show Fontname =========================
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303536/46023
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textttup}{\normalfont\ttfamily}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printexternalcurrentfont}{%
  \expandafter\format@externalcurrentfont\fontname\font:\@nil}
\def\format@externalcurrentfont#1:#2\@nil{%
  \textttup{\@ifnextchar"{\@gobble}{}#1}}
\makeatother
% ==================================

\newcommand\mysymbs{
\T\char"2660 &  \T\char"2665 & \T\char"2666 &  \T\char"2663}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
\T\printexternalcurrentfont & \mysymbs
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/715598/?

But read my final comment there before you consider running the code. Do NOT try to use it without limiting it in some way.

you could use albatross to get a list of fonts that have those characters in Unicode position which will be more managable than looping over all installed fonts. (classic tex math fonts will have them in more or less arbitrary positions use the symbols catalogue to see which fonts have them (texdoc symbols)

@DavidCarlisle Is there any way of persuading albatross to behave better as a 'nix citizen?

@cfr you mean to get the text without the fancy terminal formatting? try albatross -an -b0  -t ♠ | tail +6 | more  here, -an ansi terminal  -b0 no borders -t include tex fonts ♠  look for a spade tail +6 remove the annoying banner, more  terminal pager.

@DavidCarlisle No. I know how to get rid of the banner. I mean to get rid of all the lines like ^MESC[1A  ⠹  Please wait while we fetch the fonts.

@DavidCarlisle I want to do something like (albatross -b0 -t ♠ | sed -e '1,6/d' -e '/,.*$//') > /tmp/alb.$$.

@cfr oh I never see that and don't they go to sderr rather than stdout?  but pipe through grep -v 'Please wait if you must....

@DavidCarlisle I don't think so. Errors should show on the terminal, even if I'm redirecting stdout, but I'm only redirecting stdout. And I can't just grep because I'll lose the first font. So I need to match the line endings, too, in case I get Please wait and the first name on the same line, don't I? I can do that. It just seems weird to need to.

oh you get a please wait with no line end so it merges with the font list? that sounds wrong, I wonder why my font lookup is fast enough I never see this message You could use sed -e 's/Please.*[.]//' to remove just the text I guess, or moan at Paulo in chat and get a --just give-me-the-fonts-list` option.

I've copied the following code from my earlier answer; the only changes are the target characters and dimensions:
#!/usr/bin/env -S context --once --forcecld

---------------------
--- Configuration ---
---------------------

local target_characters = { "♠", "♥", "♦", "♣", }
local size = tex.sp("4cm")


------------
--- Code ---
------------

-- Generic wrapper so that we can use `context.step()`
context.stepwise(function() print(xpcall(function()

-- The character that we'll test each font for
local target_character = utf8.codepoint(target_characters[1])

-- Reload the font names database
if not os.getenv("OSFONTDIR") then
    os.setenv(
        "OSFONTDIR",
        "/usr/share/fonts:" .. os.getenv("HOME") .. "/.local/share/fonts/"
    )
end
fonts.names.load(true, true)

-- Get a list of all fonts on the system
local all_fonts = fonts.names.list("", true, true)

-- Configure the page layout
context.setupbodyfont { (size / 4) .. "sp" }
context.setupTABLE( { frame = "off" })
context.setupTABLE(
    { "row" }, { "each" },
    { align = "low, center", style = "tt" }
)
context.setupTABLE( { "row" }, { "first" }, { style = "ttbf" })
context.setupTABLE( { "column" }, { "each" }, { width = (1.5 * size) .. "sp" })
context.setupalign { "lesshyphenation", "verytolerant" }

-- Iterate over all the fonts
context.starttext()
for _, font in table.sortedpairs(all_fonts) do
    -- Get the full path to the font file
    local path = resolvers.findfile(font.filename)
    local hashed_path = sha2.hash256(path)

    if path:match("Fontmap") then
        -- Skip the fontmap files (not actual fonts)
        goto continue
    end

    -- Load the font
    local _, data = fonts.definers.define {
        name = path,
        filename = path,
        cs = hashed_path,
        size = size,
    }

    -- Check if the font contains the target character
    if data and data.characters and data.characters[target_character] then
        -- Begin the page
        context.step()
        context.startTEXpage { offset = (size / 2) .. "sp" }
        context.startTABLE()

        -- Print the font name
        context.NC { nc = tostring(math.min(10, #target_characters)) }
        context(file.basename(path))
        context.NC() context.NR()

        -- Print the target characters
        for i, character in ipairs(target_characters) do
            context.NC()
            context[hashed_path](character)

            if i % 10 == 0 then
                context.NC() context.NR()
            end
        end
        context.NC() context.NR()

        -- End the page
        context.stopTABLE()
        context.stopTEXpage()
    end
    ::continue::
end
context.stoptext()

-- Close the wrapper function
end, debug.traceback)) end)

And the explanation, copied verbatim:

Here, I've used ConTeXt to list all the fonts on the system, check to
see if they contain the character ა, and if so, output a page with
all the characters in the Georgian Unicode block. To run it, save it
as <filename>.cld, then run context <filename>.cld to process the
file.
This code is compatible with both the older ConTeXt MkIV (LuaTeX) and
the more recent ConTeXt LMTX (LuaMetaTeX), so it should work with (at
least) TeX Live 2021–2024.
The first time that you compile the document, it will need to create a
font cache (automatically). Once this is done, this cache will be
available for any document compiled on your system, so subsequent runs
should be pretty quick—it took me 30 seconds with LMTX, and 45 seconds
with MkIV.
However, the first run is very slow and resource intensive: with
MkIV, it took 30 minutes and used 10 GiB of memory, so you'll likely
need a computer with at least 16 GiB of RAM (and maybe a few
gigabytes of swap); with LMTX, it took 15 minutes and used 8.5 GiB of
memory. The speed and memory usage scales with the number of fonts you
have installed, so your results will likely differ.

On my computer (Linux + TeX Live 2024), I get 955 pages of output. You can view the complete PDF here; an image of the first 100 pages is below:


And I have to put this into TeXworks and run it with 'ConTeXt (LuaTeX)'?
I get "mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 256"

@cis “ConTeXt (LuaMetaTeX)” would be better if that's an option, but “ConTeXt (LuaTeX)” should work too. I can't guess what went wrong with just “fatal error”, but the log file should have some more information. If the log file is empty/non-existent, then you'll probably have to compile it manually from the command-line to see its output.

@cis Random guess: you need to save the file with a .cld extension; if the filename ends in .tex, it definitely won't work.

Ok, could work with 'test.cld'; but ends at mine with Killed mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 35072 - maybe not enough a "high end PC" -whatever...

@cis return code: 35072 means that the engine was killed by SIGKILL. I'd guess that this means that the operating system killed the process because it ran out of memory.

There must be a more efficient way that needs less memory. Based on what you wrote the final pdf holds less than 5000 glyphs. My rough guess. I would not use large tabulars, just print the glyphs in small parboxes, and use mod to make a row etc. I tried on windows different script, used kpse to get the font directories. I couldnt glob them properly and then got lazy and stopped.

Sorry for the double message. I used fontloader to open the font and then iterated to find the club symbol based on its unicode number .... printed then closed the font loader and reopened the next font etc... On a similar script just printing glyph infor etc...  On 560 pages less than 20 seconds, but the pdf is always a bottleneck, especially through a ui like TeXworks, it also seems that it has some memory leaks as well...

@yannisl The TeX/PDF parts use essentially zero memory—any TeX state is flushed as soon as the page is output, and ConTeXt is really fast until you hit 100 000+ PDF objects. The problem is that to see if a font contains a character, you need to load the entire font, and there's no way to free/delete a font once loaded, so it's not 5 000 characters, but rather every single character from every single font on your system. And these are stored directly in Lua tables, which are fairly inefficient compared to C structs or similar.

@yannisl If you add collectgarbage("collect") after context.step(), memory usage goes from 8.4 GiB to 7.2 GiB, but the time increases from 30 seconds to 10 minutes. But the issue is just the number of fonts; this is 80 000 characters and runs in 4 seconds, and this has around 200 000 PDF objects but uses fairly little memory. But there's certainly still room to optimize this, I'm just not really sure how.

@MaxChernoff Maybe you could add your result-pdf?

@cis Sure, I've edited in a link.

having a single gigantic PDF might not be most useful ; why not one cropped PDF per font, chances are OS will be able to display to user in a File system window, and filename would show fontname ; one could also perhaps typeset the fontname in the PDF. Maybe some scalable image format would be better than PDF by the way.  Maybe TeX and variants is in the end not the best tool for such things.

@MaxChernoff Thx. Now, I have a good read (1000 pages). Possibly installing one of the fonts is not a particular problem. :()

I wrote a try, but I had to delete fontnames with spaces in the following list, like  Infty Font 1.TTF, because fontspec says it can't find it.

With the command
dir /b *.ttf  > data.txt

I get a list of the kind
arial.ttf
arialbd.ttf
arialbi.ttf
ariali.ttf
ariblk.ttf
bahnschrift.ttf
calibri.ttf
calibrib.ttf
calibrii.ttf
calibril.ttf
...
...
...
...

with 168 rows at mine.
Then I used pgfplotstable in a foreach-loop to read out that list:

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\T[]{arial.ttf}% reserver name ' \T '

\newcommand\mysymbs{}

% Show Fontname =========================
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303536/46023
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textttup}{\normalfont\ttfamily}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printexternalcurrentfont}{%
  \expandafter\format@externalcurrentfont\fontname\font:\@nil}
\def\format@externalcurrentfont#1:#2\@nil{%
  \textttup{\@ifnextchar"{\@gobble}{}#1}}
\makeatother
% ==================================


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, % seems to be needed
header=false]{data.txt}\mydata
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mydata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\LastRowNo{\pgfplotsretval-1}% No. of rows

\begin{document}
Tests:

LastRowNo: \LastRowNo

\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{0}\of \mydata
Font of row 1:\pgfplotsretval


\foreach \n in {0,...,\LastRowNo}{%%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\n}{0}\of \mydata
% \pgfplotsretval
\renewfontfamily\T[]{\pgfplotsretval}%
%
\renewcommand\mysymbs{%
\T\iffontchar\font"2660 %
\char"2660 ~ \char"2665 ~\char"2666 ~ \char"2663% 
\else \texttt{-  -  -  -} \fi%
}
%
\noindent\Huge\begin{tabular}{p{1.5em}  p{9cm}  l }
\texttt{\n} &  \T\printexternalcurrentfont & \mysymbs
\end{tabular}
}%%
\end{document}


Good try, but does not answer fully your original question to get all the fonts. You need to use the LuaTeX kpse library, which can return a list of all font directories then lookup all the fonts in each directory and check if the unicode-2663 is present then print what you want....  Lua can be extremely fast in these look-ups.  Is a good exercise to learn Lua. If you have symbola is a good font for these symbols and other difficult to find such as mahjong

That's certainly true, but I can't even implement it quickly.
If you can implement this in a timely manner, please feel free to post it as a solution.

Here's an alternate solution that should use very little memory. To keep the memory usage low, this solution uses albatross to list the fonts that contain the requested characters (inspired by cfr’s answer), then it automatically restarts the compiler every 50 fonts.
This solution is compatible with both Plain LuaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but it requires shell escape for it to work properly.
\ifdefined\documentclass\else\input luaotfload.sty\fi
\catcode`\&=0
&catcode`\%=12
&catcode`\#=12
&catcode`\\=12
&directlua{
    --[[ Configuration. ]]
    local characters = "♠♥♦♣"
    local char_size = tex.sp("50pt")
    local name_size = tex.sp("10pt")

    --[[ Save some global functions to local variables for a slight performance
         boost. ]]
    local define_font = font.define
    local dimen_to_sp = tex.sp
    local hpack = node.hpack
    local max = math.max
    local new_node = node.new
    local pcall = pcall
    local read_font = fonts.definers.read
    local shipout = tex.shipout
    local tail = node.tail
    local utf_codes = utf8.codes
    local vpack = node.vpack

    --[[ Run albatross to list the fonts with the needed characters. ]]
    local command = "albatross -t -b0 -d "

    for _, code in utf_codes(characters) do
        command = command .. " " .. ("0x%x"):format(code)
    end

    local runner = io.popen(command, "r")

    if not runner then
        tex.error("Failed to run albatross.")
        return
    end

    local output = runner:read("*a")
    runner:close()

    --[[ Define the font to typeset the name. ]]
    local name_font_id
    do
        local font_data = read_font {
            name = "lmmono10-regular",
            size = name_size,
            features = {},
        }
        name_font_id = define_font(font_data)
    end

    --[[ Converts a string to a node list. ]]
    local function string_to_nodelist(string, font_id, separator)
        local head

        if separator then
            local glue = new_node("glue")
            glue.width = separator
            head = glue
        end

        for _, code in utf_codes(string) do
            local glyph = new_node("glyph")
            glyph.font = font_id
            glyph.char = code

            if separator then
                local glue = new_node("glue")
                glue.width = separator
                glyph.next = glue
            end

            if head then
                tail(head).next = glyph
            else
                head = glyph
            end
        end

        return hpack(head)
    end

    --[[ Handle re-running the file when we've used too many fonts. ]]
    local start_page
    do
        table.insert(arg, 1, arg[0])
        arg[0] = nil

        local name, number
        for i, argument in ipairs(arg) do
            if argument:match("jobname") then
                name, number = argument:match(".*=(.-)(%d+)")
                arg[i] = "--jobname=" .. name .. math.tointeger(number + 1)
                break
            end
        end

        if not name then
            table.insert(arg, 2, "--jobname=" .. tex.jobname .. "-" .. 1)
        end

        start_page = tonumber(arg[#arg])
        if not tonumber(arg[#arg]) then
            table.insert(arg, "1")
            start_page = 1
        end
    end

    --[[ Main loop. ]]
    local current_page = 0

    for filename in output:gmatch("%- ([^\n]*)\n") do
        current_page = current_page + 1

        if current_page < start_page then
            goto continue
        end

        if filename:match("Noto.*CJK") or filename:match("Noto.*Emoji") then
            --[[ Buggy font ]]
            goto continue
        end

        local status, font_data = pcall(read_font, {
            lookup = "file",
            size = char_size,
            name = filename,
            features = {},
        })

        if (not status) or (not font_data) then
            goto continue
        end

        local font_id = define_font(font_data)

        local name_box = string_to_nodelist(filename, name_font_id)

        local before_glue = new_node("glue")
        before_glue.width = name_size
        name_box.next = before_glue

        local char_box = string_to_nodelist(characters, font_id, char_size)
        before_glue.next = char_box

        local after_glue = new_node("glue")
        after_glue.width = name_size
        char_box.next = after_glue

        tex.hsize = max(name_box.width, char_box.width)
        local page = vpack(name_box)

        tex.pageheight = page.height + page.depth + name_box.height
        tex.pagewidth = page.width
        tex.hoffset = dimen_to_sp("-1in")
        tex.voffset = dimen_to_sp("-1in") + name_box.height

        tex.count[0] = current_page
        tex.box[255] = page
        shipout(255)

        arg[#arg] = tostring(current_page + 1)

        if current_page - start_page >= 50 then
            luatexbase.add_to_callback("wrapup_run", function()
                os.exec(arg)
            end, "rerun")
            break
        end

        ::continue::
    end
}&csname@@end&endcsname&end

The output will be in multiple files of 50 pages each. On my system, I get 19 files, the first of which looks like this:


Using David's comment,
$ albatross -t -b0 ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣ | sed 's/,.*$//'

generates a list of all fonts on my system which include all four characters (but probably excluding some TeX fonts with non-standard encodings).
Unfortunately, albatross doesn't seem to have an option for returning machine-parseable output (unless I missed it). The furthest it seems to go is -b0, which at least removes the 'border'. So to manipulate the results we can't just run a loop over $(albatross -t -b0 ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣ | sed 's/,.*$//'), for example. Instead, we need to redirect to a file
$ albatross -t -b0 ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣ | sed 's/,.*$//' > /tmp/alb.$$

which will create a file such as /tmp/alb.307430. If you check /tmp/alb doesn't already exist (or you have set your shell not to clobber existing files), you can dispense with the .$$ and generate /tmp/alb.
Unfortunately, albatross is really badly behaved here. Not only does it output its fancy header to the file, it also outputs numerous copies of the line
^MESC[1A  ⠋  Please wait while we map the TeX fonts.

with some additional variants mixed in such as
^MESC[1AESC[0J  ⠋  Please wait while we fetch the fonts.

Since it really ought not behave like this, I'm not sure it is wise to suggest automatic deletion. So it is probably safest to delete the unwanted lines manually. This is necessary in any case, because it is very likely that the last affected line also includes the name of the first match, but there is no way of knowing how much of the line is spurious.
So edit the file to remove the garbage. I removed 85 and a bit lines.
You'd then need a simple template such as
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \font\myfont{XXX}
  \myfont ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣ 
\end{document}

Then a simple loop in the shell can iterate through the lines of the first file, substituting the fonts into the template for XXX and typesetting the resulting file. (Use readline to change the argument separator from space to newline and rename the file before repeating the loop.)
Since I don't really want 920 of these, I tested the template with AdobePiStd and AntykwaTorunska Regular to ensure spaces aren't a problem and that I got visibly different results.
This avoids trying to typeset all the results in a single document, so there is no need to load all 920 fonts (on my system) in a single document. So it should work even on a system like mine which chokes on Max Chernoff's solution. The caveat, of course, is that you need to run a system with tools such as sed, so it is limited to 'nix-like systems (and possibly cygwin?).
With shell-escape enabled, you could also do all of this from a .tex document, but you'd still have to edit the results produced by albatross, so there's not much benefit in doing so.
Edit
Here's a bash script for Linux which creates PDFs from a file containing the list of font names. You will need to adjust PATH to your system. Or you can comment the line out and rely on the environment, but this is not recommended in general.
#!/bin/bash -
#set -x
# adjust as appropriate for your path
# or comment the line if you want to live dangerously
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH

allan=0

usage="Usage: $0 [OPTION] [FILE]
Create a PDF for each font in FILE, which should contain a list of font names.
Options:
-h --help       print this message and exit
"
error () {
echo "$@" 1>&2
((allan++))
usage_and_exit $allan
}
warning () {
echo "$@" 1>&2
((allan++))
return 1
}
usage () {
printf %b "$usage\n"
}
usage_and_exit () {
usage
exit $1
}

tempargs=$(getopt -o h --long help -- "$@")
if [ $? != 0 ];
then
usage_and_exit
fi
eval set -- "$tempargs"

while true
do
case "$1"
in
-h | --help)
usage;
exit $allan;;
--)
shift;
break;;
*)
error Unrecognised option "$1".
esac
done

args="$@"

mkdir ./alb.$$ || error "Cannot create ./alb.$$."
cp "$@" ./alb.$$/alb-list || error "Could not copy "$@" to ./alb.$$/alb-list."
cd ./alb.$$ || error "Cannot cd ./alb.$$"
mkdir ./alb-pdfs || error "Cannot create ./alb-pdfs."

cat > ./alb-template.tex <<EOF
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\font\myfont{XXX}
\myfont ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣
\end{document}
EOF

# minimal sanity
[[ -f "alb-list" ]] || error "alb-list is not a regular file."
[[ -r "alb-list" ]] || error "alb-list cannot be read."
while IFS=\n read -r j
do
printf %b "${j}:\n"
sed "s/XXX/${j}/" ./alb-template.tex > alb-tmp.tex
[[ $? != 1 ]] || error "Failed to create alb-tmp.tex."
TEXMFHOME=. lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode alb-tmp.tex || ((allan++))
[[ -e "alb-tmp.pdf" ]] && mv alb-tmp.pdf alb-pdfs/"${j}.pdf"
rm alb-tmp.tex || error "Failed to remove alb-tmp.tex."
done < alb-list

#rm alb-tmp.* alb-list || error "Failed to clean up temp files."
cd ..
printf %b "${allan} failed compilations.\n\
PDFs in alb.$$/alb-pdfs/ produced from template alb.$$/alb-template.tex.\n\
Template may be safely removed.\n"

exit $allan
# vim: ts=2:sw=2:tw=80:set nospell:

This behaves reasonably well even if compilation fails. I tested it with a truncated version of the font list. (10 fonts rather than hundreds.) This included one font LuaTeX couldn't find.
1 failed compilations.
  PDFs in alb.380704/alb-pdfs/ produced from template alb.380704/alb-template.tex.
  Template may be safely removed.

It copes fine with spaces in names:
$ ls alb.380704/alb-pdfs/
'Adobe Times Regular.pdf'  'AePagella BoldItalic.pdf'   AePagella-BoldItalic.pdf  'AntykwaTorunska Bold.pdf'        'AntykwaTorunska Italic.pdf'
AdobePiStd.pdf            'AePagella Italic.pdf'       AePagella-Italic.pdf      'AntykwaTorunska BoldItalic.pdf'  'AntykwaTorunska Regular.pdf'

I called it alb.sh, but you can name it anything you like. Either make it executable or (preferably), run it with sh <name> <path-to-file-with-font-names>. Do this in some directory you have write access to. It will create a sub-directory alb.$$ where $$ is a process number. Inside, it will create alb-pdfs/ for the PDFs and it will make a temporary copy of the list of font names. It will create a template file alb-template.tex and substitute the font names into the template, compile, rename the PDF and clean up a bit.
It reports the number of failed compilations, but does not keep track of which compilations failed.

I'm afraid I can't use Linux well enough to be able to recreate it quickly.
Can you perhaps combine this into an executable batch file?

@cis Believe me, you would not want a batch file if I wrote one. I am not running Windows and I don't know anything about it. A bash script is one thing. A batch file is an alien concept.

I meant a batch file for Linux (Mint 21.3 Cinnamon at mine). Aha: this is called a 'Shell-Script' at Linux, I read.

Something like sh mysymbs or bash mysymbs.sh I think.

I think that Albatross uses something like isatty internally, so echo | albatross seems to remove the excess output.

@MaxChernoff What does echo | albatross do exactly?

@cis Oh, a script. Sure. See edit above. Linux doesn't have batch files, so I assumed you meant for Windows (hence my rejection of the idea). It goes without saying you shouldn't run scripts from strangers on the internet without reading them. This one even produces a help message.

@MaxChernoff Also echo is usually a builtin, so shell dependent. (There is a GNU version, but it isn't generally what you get when you call echo. At least, not on Linux.)

When I paste a script into a post, why does my indentation disappear?

@cfr echo | albatross makes it so that stdin is a pipe instead of a terminal. Albatross seems to check if its stdin is a terminal: if it is, it uses “pretty” output; if it isn't, it suppresses the loading bar. It doesn't matter that echo is a shell builtin in this case; yes | albatross, cat some-file | albatross, and echo test | albatross should all give the same results.

@MaxChernoff Wait, you mean it checks stdin but not stdout? Aargh!

@cfr I seem to be mistaken, it appears to check both on my system. I don't get the Please wait stuff on my system with albatross -t -b0 ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣ | tee /dev/null, but I also don't get Please wait with echo | albatross ....

@MaxChernoff If it is called from a shell script, it still prints the lines, which it shouldn't, if it is detecting whether it is getting stdin. What system are you on? Note that I don't get those lines the return is to stdout.

@cfr This seems to work for me albatross -an -b0  -t ♠ | tail +6 | grep -v '(family)' | sed -e 's/,.*//'

@DavidCarlisle it doesn't work for me. Did you redirect to a file? It's fine otherwise.

no just piped through more but what fails for you?

@DavidCarlisle If I redirect to file, I get numerous garbage lines. And the final one is typically interrupted by the first font name. ^MESC[1A  ⠼  Please wait while we fetch the fonts. ^MESC[1AESC[0JAdobe Gothic Std L for example.

I'm using bash in wsl ubuntu and get a pure ascii file with one font per line if I redirect to a file

@DavidCarlisle I posted the beginning of what I get in chat.

@cfr I'm using an up-to-date TL24 on Fedora 40 and I get the exact same as David.

@MaxChernoff I have not-quite up-to-date TL24 on Arch. I doubt that's the problem.
